# Did King get any stronger?

Tags: one-punch-man

At the end of season 2 episode 1 , Saitama asks King if he's going to keep lying about being strong and King says he doesnt know. Then Saitama tells him he could quit or get stronger. Did King get any stronger as the story continues? (in the manga)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He supposedly develops a guilt and fear due to the lie he is hiding from others. According to the [wiki](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/King),

> ...he decided to visit Bang in his dojo and asked him to train him, in order to become stronger. After getting rejected however, he desperately tried the same with Bomb's dojo and later visited one dojo after another, only to get rejected over and over again, thus making him even more desperate. As a result **he eventually dropped the thought of getting stronger** and even considered the idea to die while attempting to fight a monster.

Unless he has the drive or the will to become stronger again in the future, then *no, he will not get any stronger anytime soon*.

Comment: I thought Bang hanged out with him and Saitama? Too bad, it would have been cool if he got some martial arts skills and artifacts to get stronger

Comment: @Pablo King just can't escape his reputation. Everyone interprets everything he says and does as the action of a supremely powerful man.

Comment: @Pablo Also, so you know, this answer is based on recent events in the webcomic, which is technically distinct from the manga. The manga is based on the webcomic, and mostly just expands on things in the webcomic, but there are some differences so it's probable but not certain that these webcomic events will also appear in the manga in some form once it advances to that point.